# Google Cloud - Check if Bucket Exists Using Credentials

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to implement a method to check if a particular bucket exists in google cloud. The function takes in a bucket name `gs://my-bucket/`, for example, and a stringified version of a credentials JSON. I convert the credentials string to an input stream in order to pass it into the `setCredentials` method (not sure if there is a way to do this by passing the string directly in - haven't found one in the API). However, after doing this, I get an error related to an invalid precondition. I essentially ripped this method straight from the google cloud Java API storage examples (albeit in Scala), so I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Code:

```
  def bucketExists(bucketName: String, credentials: String): Boolean = {
    val credentialStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(credentials.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder
      .setCredentials(
        ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(credentialStream))
      .build
      .getService
    storage.get(bucketName, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields()).exists()
}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.optionMap(StorageImpl.java:945)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.optionMap(StorageImpl.java:937)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.optionMap(StorageImpl.java:967)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:250)
        at models.services.CloudServiceImpl.bucketExists(CloudServiceImpl.scala:726)
        at models.services.CloudServiceImpl.genomicsETL(CloudServiceImpl.scala:591)
        at controllers.AuthController$$anonfun$ingestDataSource$1$$anonfun$apply$44.apply(AuthController.scala:339)
        at controllers.AuthController$$anonfun$ingestDataSource$1$$anonfun$apply$44.apply(AuthController.scala:327)
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
```

Edit:

Swapped `storage.get(bucketName, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields()).exists()` to `storage.get(bucketName).exists()` and got what I believe to be a better exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:75)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:53)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:165)
        at models.services.CloudServiceImpl.bucketExists(CloudServiceImpl.scala:725)
```

I believe this indicates that there's multiple google guava versions causing a conflict and can potentially be resolved with shading. May need to verify where the guava versions are coming from (best guess is play and the google cloud console).

Comment: Curious: was multiple Guava versions the issue? I saw your unanswered question and happened to be writing similar code. I rejigged my code to reflect (your summary of) yours and it works for me. So I assume it was a Guava conflict.

Comment: Yes - we ended up having guava versions `20.0.0` and `jdk5:17.0.0`. Looks like the `google-api-client` dependency still uses the `jdk5` version.